# AD calls over 3269 querying non ssl DC servers

Tags: c#, ssl, active-directory, ldap, directoryservices

AD calls over 3269 are querying non ssl DC servers as not all Domain Controllers are ssl enabled in the forest.
AD calls(by passing global catalog server) should query at the forest level and in our case, not all the DC's are ssl enabled, hence only when GC call selects the SSL enabled DC for querying we get results, when it selects the non ssl DC, it throws error as "the server is not operational".

As AD calls(by passing global catalog server) selects the Domain Controller server randomly (based on location and load), calls are failing most of the time, can we apply any filters to GC calls(DirectoryEntry) to query only SSL enabled DC servers?
Or any other suggestion to filter only SSL enabled DC's during GC call on port number 3269, please suggest.
I am using System.DirectoryServices in C# to make a GC call.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is a `GC call`?

Comment: Am making a call to AD by providing Global Catalog url.
Ex: DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("GC://mydomain.example.com");

Comment: Can you share a [mcve]?

Comment: You can always bind to a specific domain controller (that you know you can reach with SSL) instead of binding to a domain.